# Algoritmo de números adjacentes com complexidade O (N * log (N))

Tags: c#

Fiz um algoritmo que retorna o valor minimo entre duas distancias em um determinado array. Gostaria de saber se ainda ha alguma forma de melhorar o algoritmo olhando para complexidade O(N*log(N)). Abaixo o enunciado.

Escrever uma função que, dado um array A não-vazia com índice zero consiste em inteiros N, retorna o mínimo distância entre os índices desta matriz que têm valores adjacentes. A função deve retornar -1 se a distância mínima é superior a 100 milhões. A função deve retornar -2 se não houver índices adjacentes.

Assuma isso:

 N é um número inteiro dentro do intervalo [1..40,000];

 cada elemento da matriz A é um número inteiro dentro do intervalo

[-2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647]

Complexidade:

 esperado complexidade de tempo de pior caso é O (N * log (N));

 esperado espaço de complexidade do pior caso é O (N), além do armazenamento de entrada (não

```
public static int solution(int[] A)
                {
                    int resultado = int.MaxValue;

                    if (A.Length < 2 || A == null)
                        return -2;

                    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < A.Length; j++)
                        {
                            if (Math.Abs(A[i] - A[j]) < resultado)
                                resultado = Math.Abs(A[i] - A[j]);
                        }
                    }

                    if (resultado > 100000000)
                        return -1;

                    return resultado;
                }
```

Comment: A pergunta é se o código esta ok, sim esta ok... funciona para oque você informou no enunciado. Existem sim algumas variações.. você pode utilizar algumas opções do c# para facilitar algumas coisas como Tupple, Listas etc... e até mesmo multitarefas(multithread).

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a resposta:

[Valores adjacentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112735/valores-adjacentes/112790#112790)

Aparentemente, falta a definição do que é `valor adjacente` para o problema descrito na pergunta.

Uma possibilidade, **caso a regra** para `valor adjacente` seja:

> ...
>   Um array A não-vazio com índice zero contém N inteiros.
>
> Um par de índices (P, Q) onde 0 ≤ P < Q < N, é dito adjacente, se nenhum valor
>   "encontra-se estritamente" entre A[P] e A[Q].
>    ...

está no post do **SO** em inglês [Compute Adjacent Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062262/trying-to-sort-and-find-the-nearest-pair-of-adjacent-values-in-an-array-in-c-sha#35063031) (código extraído da resposta original):

```
Array.Sort(A);

for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
{
    // equivalent to
    // if (Math.Abs(A[i] - A[i + 1]) < shortestDistance)
    //  shortestDistance = Math.Abs(A[i] - A[i + 1]);
    shortestDistance = Math.Abs(A[i] - A[i + 1]) < shortestDistance ? Math.Abs(A[i] - A[i + 1]) : shortestDistance;
}

// return −1 if the minimum distance is greater than 100,000,000
if (shortestDistance > 100000000)
{
    return -1;
}

return shortestDistance;
```

Complexidade:

- Ordenar o vetor: `O(N*log(N))`
- Encontrar o menor valor: `O(N)`

Como: `O(N*log(N) + N) = O(N*log(N))`

Portanto, **caso a regra seja a descrita acima**, o código postado no SO em inglês é uma alternativa para solucionar o problema com uma complexidade **O(n log n)**.