# Valores adjacentes

Tags: algoritmo, matriz, array, lógica

Preciso criar uma algoritmo que calcule o valor mínimo de distância entre os índices de uma matriz que contem **valores adjacentes**. Mas o que são **valores adjacentes** alguém poderia me dar exemplos?

Por exemplo, na matriz A tal que:

```
  A [0] = 0
  A [1] = 3
  A [2] = 3
  A [3] = 7
  A [4] = 5
  A [5] = 3
  A [6] = 11
  A [7] = 1
```

Os seguintes pares de valores têm índices adjacentes:

(0, 7), (1, 2), (1, 4),

(1, 5), (1, 7), (2, 4),

(2, 5), (2, 7), (3, 4),

(3, 6), (4, 5), (5, 7).

Os índices 4 e 5 têm valores adjacentes porque não há nenhum valor no array A

que se encontra estritamente entre A [4] = 5 e A [5] = 3; a única tal valor poderia ser o número 4,

e que não está presente na matriz.

Comment: Existe o conceito de valor adjacente em estatística.

Comment: @Pablo Quero entender a logica desse exemplo.

Comment: @AlUnserAlbuquerque vou responder, mas o texto vai ficar um pouco extenso.

Comment: @Gomiero tudo bem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valores adjacentes podem ter muitos significados diferentes, e dependem, principalmente, do enunciado do problema e da área a qual ele se aplica.

Dois exemplos passo-a-passo, para mostrar regras diferentes para o conceito **valores adjacentes**.

### Exemplo 1

Extraído da pergunta no SO em inglês:

[Trying to sort and find the nearest pair of adjacent values in an array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062262/trying-to-sort-and-find-the-nearest-pair-of-adjacent-values-in-an-array-in-c-sha)

Neste caso, a regra é:

> ...
>   Um array A não-vazio com índice zero contém N inteiros.
>   Um par de índices (P, Q) onde 0 ≤ P < Q < N, é dito adjacente, se nenhum valor  "encontra-se estritamente" entre A[P] e A[Q].
>   ...

Aqui, a regra para criar as tuplas **(P, Q)** indica que não pode haver valores
intermediários entre 2 elementos, portanto:

```
Valor   |  0 |  3 |  3 |  7 |  5 |  3 | 11 |  1 |  
--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+  
Índice  |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
```

Tuplas **(P, Q)** de índices (explicação segue a notação `valor[índice]` ou `valor`):

```
(0, 1)  => não, porque tem o valor 1[7] entre 0 e 3
(0, 2)  => não, porque tem o valor 1[7] entre 0 e 3
(0, 3)  => não, porque tem o valores 1[7] e 5[4] entre 0 e 7
(0, 4)  => não, porque tem o valor 1[7] e 3[1] entre 0 e 5
(0, 5)  => não, porque tem o valor 1[7] entre 0 e 3
(0, 6)  => não, porque tem o valores 1[7], 3[1], 5[4] e 7[3] entre 0 e 11
(0, 7)  => SIM, porque não há valor entre 0 e 1 (adjacentes)

(1, 2)  => SIM, porque não há valor entre 3 e 3 (adjacentes)
(1, 3)  => não, porque tem o valor 5[4] entre 3 e 7
(1, 4)  => SIM, porque não há valor entre 3 e 5 (adjacentes)
(1, 5)  => SIM, porque não há valor entre 3 e 3 (adjacentes)
(1, 6)  => não, porque tem o valores 5[4] e 7[3] entre 3 e 11
(1, 7)  => SIM, porque não há valor entre 3 e 1 (adjacentes)

(2, 3)  => não, porque tem o valor 5[4] entre 3 e 7
(2, 4)  => SIM, porque não há valor entre 3 e 5 (adjacentes)
.....
.....
.....
```

E seguindo esses passos, obtém-se o conjunto das tuplas:

```
(0, 7), (1, 2), (1, 4),
(1, 5), (1, 7), (2, 4),
(2, 5), (2, 7), (3, 4),
(3, 6), (4, 5), (5, 7)
```

---

### Exemplo 2

Semelhante à pergunta feita por você em:

[Algoritmo de números adjacentes com complexidade O (N * log (N))](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112552/algoritmo-de-n%c3%bameros-adjacentes-com-complexidade-o-n-log-n)

estou supondo que a origem seja parecida com o seguinte desafio no site Codility:

[Shortest Adjacency Sequency](https://codility.com/programmers/task/shortest_adj_seq/)

(Não copiei o texto aqui devido a direitos autorais,
mas é só clicar no link e no botão `View` no site)

Deve se achar o menor caminho do primeiro elemento (`1`) ao último elemento (`2`),
seguindo as regras descritas no [link](https://codility.com/programmers/task/shortest_adj_seq/) acima.

Vetor de exemplo:

```
Valor   |  1 | 10 |  6 |  5 | 10 |  7 |  5 |  2 |
--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
Índice  |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
```

Alguns caminhos possíveis (explicação segue a notação `valor[índice]` ou valor):

`[1, 10, 6, 5, 10, 7, 5, 2]`

**Explicação:** é o próprio vetor original.

`[1, 10, 6, 5, 10, 7, => 5, 10, 7, 5, 2]`

**Explicação:** Percorre o vetor até o valor `5[6]`, volta para o valor `5[3]` (adjacente) e continua até o final.

`[1, 10, 6, 5, => 10, 6, 5, 10, 7, 5, 2]`

**Explicação:** Percorre o vetor até o valor `10[4]`, volta para o valor `10[1]` (adjacente) e continua até o final.

`[1, => 10, 7, 5, 2]`;

**Explicação:** Percorre o vetor até o valor `10[1]`, pula para o valor `10[4]` (adjacente) e continua até o final.

`[1, => 10, => 5, 2]`

**Explicação:** Percorre o vetor até o valor `10[1]`, pula para o valor `10[4]` (adjacente), volta para o valor `5[3]` (anterior), pula para o valor `5[6]` (adjacente) e continua até o final.

Neste exemplo, segundo o problema, a solução (menor caminho) é o `[1, 10, 5, 2]`.

---

Portanto, o termo `valores adjacentes`  depende da regra especificada no problema e, também, a área onde o termo é utilizado (conforme os comentários).

Abaixo, segue uma implementação (em Python) do exemplo 2:

[Codility Iota 2011 Coding Challenge - ShortestAdjSeq](http://www.lucainvernizzi.net/blog/2014/11/25/codility-iota-2011-coding-challenge/)

Comment: Perfeito exemplo bem claro para o solução do meu problema. Obrigado